# A standard license for a closed source library

Tags: java, licensing

I'm looking for an standard license for a closed source library. Basically I want to allow to use just the binary even in commercial projects. Disallowing modifications.

Is there some standard license that fits my needs?

Comment: In our closed source, I say; there is no license to use, redistribute or modify this code except where allowed by a contract with us.

Comment: Creative Commons Attribution NoDerivs (CC-ND)

Comment: @MuratK. Thanks it is what I was looking for, please post as answer to accept it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange](//programmers.stackexchange.com), but [**read their faq carefully** before proceeding](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Creative Commons Attribution NoDerivs (CC-ND)

which includes following:

Can:

- Commercial Use
- Distribute

Can't:

- Sublicense
- Place Warranty
- Hold Liable
- **Modify**

Must:

- Include Copyright

Source: https://tldrlegal.com/license/creative-commons-attribution-noderivs-(cc-nd)

I would still look further into it to be perfectly sure it's suited for oneself.

Comment: Creative Commons is not a closed source license.  The OP explicitly wants to disallow source access. CC explicitly grants rights to source code.  The OP would literally be better off adding nothing at all than adding CC.